# Display already visited highlight on pic.twitter on popular browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, url, twitter

I'm a heavy twitter user and I follow a lot of people and companies. As you can imagine when searching to discover new things a lot of people share images!

The problem is that the pictures are retweeted over and over and a lot of the times I've already checked them out and it wastes my time. I've tried using both Chrome and Firefox and it seems that already visited links do not work on twitter.

I've attached an image to give you an example what I'm referring to:

[image]

It is all links using `pic.twitter`, I believe this might be because they use `to.co/STRING`.

***SHORT VERSION***

How do you enable highlighting on previously visited images on twitter using popular browsers.